# StackOverFlowError using EasyMock v3.3

Tags: easymock, stack-overflow

I thought StackOverFlowError was resolved in EasyMock v3.2 (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/EASYMOCK-113). I am encountering this error while using v3.3. Does anybody have a solution for this in how test cases should be written?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:143)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:65)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
        at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
        at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7f8efe81.getAuthorities(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.AbstractAuthenticationToken.equals(AbstractAuthenticationToken.java:80)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7f8efe81.CGLIB$equals$3(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7f8efe81$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ba75b65d.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7f8efe81.equals(<generated>)
        at org.easymock.internal.Invocation.equals(Invocation.java:99)
        at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.equals(ExpectedInvocation.java:74)
        at org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior.allowsExpectedInvocation(UnorderedBehavior.java:108)
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addBehaviorListIfNecessary(MocksBehavior.java:74)
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addExpected(MocksBehavior.java:60)
        at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.times(RecordState.java:192)
        at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.closeMethod(RecordState.java:234)
        at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.invoke(RecordState.java:76)
        at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
        at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
        at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7f8efe81.getAuthorities(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.AbstractAuthenticationToken.equals(AbstractAuthenticationToken.java:80)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7f8efe81.CGLIB$equals$3(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7f8efe81$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ba75b65d.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7f8efe81.equals(<generated>)
        at org.easymock.internal.Invocation.equals(Invocation.java:99)
        at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.equals(ExpectedInvocation.java:74)
        at org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior.allowsExpectedInvocation(UnorderedBehavior.java:108)
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addBehaviorListIfNecessary(MocksBehavior.java:74)
        at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addExpected(MocksBehavior.java:60)
        at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.times(RecordState.java:192)
        at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.closeMethod(RecordState.java:234)
        at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.invoke(RecordState.java:76)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I noticed in the stack trace that "getAuthorties()" method was being invoked. I mocked response to this method as below and eliminated StackOverFlowError.

```
        EasyMock.expect(mockNamePwdAuthToken.getAuthorities()).andReturn(
                null);
```